# Nonanchored Substring Query a field with Loopback API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs

I am trying to implement a simple substring query with the loopback api for a typeahead field, perhaps I'm blind, but I have been looking all over for an answer to this.

I would just like to provide it with a substring, and have it return all brands with that substring in the name.

For example this request `/api/brands/search?q=tas` would return.

```
[{
  "brandName": "TastyKakes",
  "id": "4"
},
{
  "brandName": "FantasticPastries",
  "id": "10"
}]
```

I wrote a remoteMethod to handle this but I can't quite get it to return the data I am looking for

```
  Brand.search = function (q, callback) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(q, "i");
    var brands = Brand.find({
      where: {
        brandName: {
          like: pattern
        }
      }
    }, function (err, data) {
      callback(err, data)
    })
  };
```

I am new to Loopback / Node / Express, but I am coming from a Python / Django background, and doing something like this in django is pretty simple. I feel like I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this can be done by ilike %% no case in where clause like this no need of pattern

```
Brand.search = function (q, callback) {
var pattern = "%s" + q + "%s";
var brands = Brand.find({
  where: {
    brandName: {
      ilike: pattern
    }
  }
}, function (err, data) {
  callback(err, data)
})
};
```

For more details see [HERE](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html#ilike-and-nilike)

Comment: I should have clarified that I am using mysql, but your answer put me on the right path. 

What worked was actually setting the pattern as follows
`var pattern = "%s" + q + "%s";`

and instead of using ilike, which led to some errors just using like. `like: pattern`